# R combine data.frame with varying length in a column

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have a problem and I would like to apologize, if this problem has been already discussed, eventhough I checked old postings.

I have a data.frame with 2 columns, the second column can contain several identifier, but the number can vary. In another data.frame the identifiers corresponds to another identifier.

```
df.1  

color   identifier
blue    A1, B2, C3, C4 
yellow  B2, C4, C6
green   A3

df.2

A1 Mercedes
A3 BMW
B2 Porsche
C3 Toyota
C4 Hundai
C5 Volkswagen
C6 Peugeot
```

What I would like to have is a data.frame like this:

```
df.3

color   identifier        identifier2
blue    A1, B2, C3, C4    Mercedes, Porsche, Toyota, Hundai 
yellow  B2, C4, C6        Porsche, Hundai, Peugeot
green   A3                BMW
```

A data.frame which contains the identifiers and additionally the identifiers of the second data.frame.

I was trying to use apply and stack and unstack, but I was not successful at all.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another solution, using `strsplit`:

```
# The data
df.1  = read.table(header=TRUE, text="
color   identifier
blue    'A1, B2, C3, C4'
yellow  'B2, C4, C6'
green   'A3'", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df.2 = read.table(header=FALSE, text="
A1 Mercedes
A3 BMW
B2 Porsche
C3 Toyota
C4 Hundai
C5 Volkswagen
C6 Peugeot", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(df.2) = c("identifier", "car")

df.1$identifier = strsplit(df.1$identifier, split=", ")
df.1$identifier1 = lapply(1:nrow(df.1), 
         function(x) df.2[which(df.2$identifier %in% df.1$identifier[[x]]), 2])
df.1
#    color     identifier                       identifier1
# 1   blue A1, B2, C3, C4 Mercedes, Porsche, Toyota, Hundai
# 2 yellow     B2, C4, C6          Porsche, Hundai, Peugeot
# 3  green             A3                               BMW
```

Note that `identifier` and `identifier1` are now *lists* in your `data.frame`. I personally find this easier to work with later on.

```
str(df.1)
# 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  3 variables:
#   $ color      : chr  "blue" "yellow" "green"
# $ identifier :List of 3
#  ..$ : chr  "A1" "B2" "C3" "C4"
#  ..$ : chr  "B2" "C4" "C6"
#  ..$ : chr "A3"
# $ identifier1:List of 3
#  ..$ : chr  "Mercedes" "Porsche" "Toyota" "Hundai"
#  ..$ : chr  "Porsche" "Hundai" "Peugeot"
#  ..$ : chr "BMW"
```

You may need to modify the `strsplit` if there is any whitespace left over, but it works with this sample data. Also, for `strsplit` to work, the data need to be in mode `as.character` (hence my use of `stringsAsFactors` when reading in the data).

## Update: write.table()

I *do* prefer to keep the data in lists in case I wanted to do further analysis. However, if the data are complete or just for output purposes, you might want to do something like this:

```
df.3 = df.1
df.3$identifier = sapply(df.3$identifier, paste0, collapse=", ")
df.3$identifier1 = sapply(df.3$identifier1, paste0, collapse=", ")
```

This will allow you to use `write.table` since `identifier` and `identifier1` are now of mode `character` instead of `list`.

Comment: But is it really easier to work on with lists within the data.frame? E.g. I get error messages if I try to write a table.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the easiest way is to use a regular expression with `gsub` to do the replacement.

Recreate your data:

```
df1 <- read.table(text="
color   identifier
blue    'A1, B2, C3, C4'
yellow  'B2, C4, C6'
green   A3
", header=TRUE)


df2 <- read.table(text="
A1 Mercedes
A3 BMW
B2 Porsche
C3 Toyota
C4 Hundai
C5 Volkswagen
C6 Peugeot 
", header=FALSE)
```

And now you have to loop through each element of your colour lookup (`df2`) and make the replacement in `df1`:

```
for (i in seq_len(nrow(df2))){
  df1$identifier <- gsub(df2[i, 1], df2[i, 2], df1$identifier)
}
```

The result:

```
df1
   color                        identifier
1   blue Mercedes, Porsche, Toyota, Hundai
2 yellow          Porsche, Hundai, Peugeot
3  green                               BMW
```

Comment: Thank you Andrie for your suggestion.